# Adding angular to extension content script code

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to manipulate the text fields on a website through chrome-extension. But since the website is written in angular, I would need to edit the text field using the angular code. 
For using angular in the code, I would need to define the angular script in the scope of my extension. I'm declaring in the following way.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js";
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

But this again throws the error that angular is not defined and my functions would not run. Please show me how to define angular and where to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the angular script in your manifest.json like below:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "scripts/angular.min.js",
        "scripts/content.js"
    ],
    "css": [
        "stylesheets/content.css"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I did try adding angular in my manifest, but it was showing conflicting errors with the jQuery library. Any work around?